# Wp_query loop is not working as it should

Tags: posts, wp-query, loop, slideshow

I have a slide loop on my site that I set to show only 2 but it is showing more than that, it will probably create more slides as I post more.

Each slide is a li tag and I'm trying to use this loop to show 2

What's wrong with my code?

[My Site](http://gamersaction.com/)

[The Slides plugin i'm using](http://responsiveslides.com/)

```
<div class="intro-slides">
<ul class="rslides">

    <?php $args = array ('post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 2 );
            $the_query = new WP_Query ( $args );
            while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

    <li>
            <div class="intro-noticias">    
                <?php $args = array ('post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'post__not_in' => $do_not_duplicate );
                $the_query = new WP_Query ( $args );
                while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID; ?>
                <div class="intro-noticia-1">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <?php $backgroundImg = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'large' );?>
                <div class="intro-post-thumbnail" style="background: url('<?php echo $backgroundImg[0]; ?>'); background-size: cover; background-position: center;">
                <div class="intro-noticia-main-caption">
                    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                    <div>
                    <span class="intro-main-caption-autor"><?php the_author(); ?></span>
                    <span class="intro-main-caption-time"><?php printf( _x( '%s atrás', '%s = human-readable time difference', 'your-text-domain' ), human_time_diff( get_the_time( 'U' ), current_time( 'timestamp' ) ) ); ?></span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                </div></a>
                </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

                <?php $args = array ('post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'cat' => 'cat=2', 'post__not_in' => $do_not_duplicate );
                $the_query = new WP_Query ( $args );
                while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID; ?>
                <div class="intro-noticia-2">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <?php $backgroundImg = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'medium' );?>
                <div class="intro-post-thumbnail" style="background: url('<?php echo $backgroundImg[0]; ?>'); background-size: cover; background-position: center;">
                <div class="intro-noticia-secondary-caption">
                    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                    <div>
                    <span class="intro-secondary-caption-autor"><?php the_author(); ?></span>
                    <span class="intro-secondary-caption-time"><?php printf( _x( '%s atrás', '%s = human-readable time difference', 'your-text-domain' ), human_time_diff( get_the_time( 'U' ), current_time( 'timestamp' ) ) ); ?></span>
                  </div>
                    </div>
                </div></a>
                </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

                <?php $args = array ('post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'cat' => 'cat=3', 'post__not_in' => $do_not_duplicate );
                $the_query = new WP_Query ( $args );
                while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID; ?>
                <div class="intro-noticia-3">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <?php $backgroundImg = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'medium' );?>
                <div class="intro-post-thumbnail" style="background: url('<?php echo $backgroundImg[0]; ?>'); background-size: cover; background-position: center;">
                <div class="intro-noticia-secondary-caption">
                    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                    <div>
                    <span class="intro-secondary-caption-autor"><?php the_author(); ?></span>
                    <span class="intro-secondary-caption-time"><?php printf( _x( '%s atrás', '%s = human-readable time difference', 'your-text-domain' ), human_time_diff( get_the_time( 'U' ), current_time( 'timestamp' ) ) ); ?></span>
                  </div>
                    </div>
                </div></a>
                </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

                <?php $args = array ('post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'cat' => 'cat=4', 'post__not_in' => $do_not_duplicate );
                $the_query = new WP_Query ( $args );
                while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID; ?>
                <div class="intro-noticia-4">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <?php $backgroundImg = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'medium' );?>
                <div class="intro-post-thumbnail" style="background: url('<?php echo $backgroundImg[0]; ?>'); background-size: cover; background-position: center;">
                <div class="intro-noticia-secondary-caption">
                    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                    <div>
                    <span class="intro-secondary-caption-autor"><?php the_author(); ?></span>
                    <span class="intro-secondary-caption-time"><?php printf( _x( '%s atrás', '%s = human-readable time difference', 'your-text-domain' ), human_time_diff( get_the_time( 'U' ), current_time( 'timestamp' ) ) ); ?></span>
                  </div>
                    </div>
                </div></a>
                </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

                <?php $args = array ('post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'cat' => 'cat=5', 'post__not_in' => $do_not_duplicate );
                $the_query = new WP_Query ( $args );
                while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID; ?>
                <div class="intro-noticia-5">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <?php $backgroundImg = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'medium' );?>
                <div class="intro-post-thumbnail" style="background: url('<?php echo $backgroundImg[0]; ?>'); background-size: cover; background-position: center;">
                <div class="intro-noticia-secondary-caption">
                    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                    <div>
                    <span class="intro-secondary-caption-autor"><?php the_author(); ?></span>
                    <span class="intro-secondary-caption-time"><?php printf( _x( '%s atrás', '%s = human-readable time difference', 'your-text-domain' ), human_time_diff( get_the_time( 'U' ), current_time( 'timestamp' ) ) ); ?></span>
                  </div>
                    </div>
                </div></a>
            </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
            </div>

            </li>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmmm - you are re-using the same variable for both the outer and the inner queries... ("$the_query") You might want to start by making each variable unique? Also, I'm pretty sure you just need `wp_reset_postdata();` - you can drop the `wp_reset_query();` calls, which could be causing issues of their own.

Comment: You shouldn't nest queries and use the same variable name, also `post__not_in` is super slow/expensive, it's faster to manually skip a post in PHP than it is to tell the database

Comment: @MacPrawn Changing the 1st variable of the query worked, so the ideal is to put a different variable for each query?

Comment: @TomJNowell Do you have any articles that explain this better and show how to do?

Comment: @GabrielSouza absoplutely - otherwise your variable is overridden on each internal loop...

Comment: @MacPrawn Is it recommended that the variable $args be different too?

Comment: Well, you could get away with that one, because the value's been used when you created the query. You'll want to read a good book on variable scope to demystify all of this...

Comment: @GabrielSouza imagine you have to give commands to 100 people, and you have to be very precise about who you give what task or they'll be confused, except you're only allowed to call them Bob. Don't reuse variable names ( `$the_query` )